# Python Comma Seperate Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand how this comma separated solution works and how it is called, example:

```
b, c=0, 5
print(b,c)

>>0 5
```

1. Why is variable 'b' value 0?
2. Why is variable 'c' value 5?

Comment: You can unpack iterables in assginment. `b,c=0,5` is the same as `b=0;c=5`

Comment: Your first line is equivalent to `(b, c) = (0, 5)`

Comment: You can take a look at this [ressource](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/)

Comment: Oh wow, I will hide in a corner now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Comma separated values are interpreted as tuple, which can be unpacked:

```
t = 0,5 # sames as t = (0,5)
print(type(t))
a,b = t
print(a,b)
```

Out:

```
<class 'tuple'>
0 5
```